# Why does only the Horizon render, but not objects?

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, world

So, whenever I render a image, only the sky shows up.

[image: render of only the sky]

but, it is supposed to show like this:

[image: viewport screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I found out myself, all  I had to was clear restricted renders.

Comment: Will you please add more to your answer. Maybe telling where to find the restricted render, or a screen shot. Thanks.